# Creating a custom cachedependency for documents in ravendb

Tags: asp.net, caching, ravendb, cache-dependency

I'm trying to create cache dependency to expire some documents i'm caching using ASP.NET Cache. I came up with this:

```
public class DocumentCacheDependency : CacheDependency
{
    private readonly IDisposable _Subscription;

    public DocumentCacheDependency(IDocumentStore store, string docId)
    {
        _Subscription = store.Changes().ForDocument(docId).Subscribe(OnDocumentChanged);
        FinishInit();
    }

    private void OnDocumentChanged(DocumentChangeNotification documentChangeNotification)
    {
        NotifyDependencyChanged(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    protected override void DependencyDispose()
    {
        _Subscription.Dispose();
        base.DependencyDispose();
    }
}
```

Is this a good idea performance wise or should i use the "ForDocumentsStartingWith" / "ForAllDocuments". Or should i create an index.
The answer probably depends on the number of documents being cached, so i guess what i'm asking is, is RavenDB optimizing anything for me out of the box when i register hundreds of change listeners, or will the client actually set up hunderds of connections with the db this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably better off not doing this at all.
RavenDB is already going to do caching for you without any cost on your end.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but won't the Raven client be querying the server only to receive a "Not Modified" back (unless Aggressive Caching is enabled)? I could see how the custom cache dependency approach might be ideal for certain very performance critical areas right?